# how to store cookies in a variable from the response of the login page and use it in further requests

Tags: python

I am using below code to login to a website

```
url = 'http://12.345.67.891:8000/login'
values = {'User': 'abcdefg',
          'password': 'apple'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print(r.content)
```

As a response of the above code i am getting output as

```
"{"message":"Logged in"}"
```

But when i manually browse through the website. Once i logged in it is redirecting to a page which is homepage. In that home page response i can see cookies are available which we can use in the further requests. Can someone of you please help me to find how to store cookies in a variable from the response of the login redirected home page and use it in further requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `requests.Session`, as it [should persist cookies across all requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/):

```
s = requests.Session()
url = 'http://12.345.67.891:8000/login'
values = {'User': 'abcdefg',
          'password': 'apple'}

r = s.post(url, data=values)
# rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you, i am able to get the required output by implementing "s = requests.Session()" code